# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000000"

Tags: visual-c++

Написал прогу, нет ошибок, все скомпилировалось, но выдает ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение в "0x003015c5" в "laba_1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000000".

Comment: Язык в метки, код в вопрос (**не в комментарий**). Мы же не будем угадывать, что вы написали, нихт?) 

А вообще это скорее всего использование неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки это Visual C++ 2008.

Answer (score 7):

Вам надо запустить программу под отладчиком и дойти до точки, где происходит исключение. Скорее всего верно предположение Sh4dow, хотя это может быть и выход за границы массива, и неправильная работа с указателями, и ошибка работы с адресной арифметикой, и т.п.